# "Niveous" poetic synonyms

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, poetry

Are there any more poetic synonyms for "snow-white" and "niveous"? I was searching but I've only found "nival".

Answer (score 2):

*[Pristine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pristine)*, *[sparkling](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sparkling)*, and *[glistening](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glistening)* are sometimes used of snow, the latter from  *[glisten](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glisten)*, “to reflect light with a glittering luster; to sparkle, coruscate, glint or flash”.

Comparisons or contrasts like milk-white are sometimes used; eg, in *[Surrey with the Fringe on Top](http://www.thepeaches.com/music/composers/hammerstein/SurreyWithTheFringeOnTop.htm)*,

> [Shirley]
>   Has it really got a team of snow-white horses?
>
> [Gordon]
>   One's like snow~the other's more like milk.

and in [Lamentations 4:7](http://biblehub.com/lamentations/4-7.htm),

> Her consecrated ones were brighter than snow, whiter than milk...

Here are a few other combinations that might be poetically shoehornable:  *[frosty](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frosty#Adjective)* *[effulgence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effulgence)*, *[chionablepsic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chionablepsia) brightness* or *radiance*, *brilliant [poudrin](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=poudrin)*.